# Environment texture for background does not show up in node editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I've added a environment texture as my background as well as lighting for a house. It works fine. At one point I could edit the environment texture as well as adjusting hue or brightness in the node editor. But now I couldn't figure out how to bring it back. The node editor only shows the last selected object. And I can't select "world" in the outliner either. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select world materials in the *Node editor* by pressing the world icon in the header:

[image]

The cube icon will switch back to showing object materials.

Comment: How do you get to this screen? If I click on the "shading" tab at the top I get to a node editor, but that "world" icon is not there.

Comment: Oh, I found it, finally. You have to click where it says "object", which brings up a dropdown, and you can select "world" from there. It's probably a change in 2.8