# Rendered environment map is misaligned to World

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, coordinates, world

I modeled a sun, placed it up in the sky of my scene, and rendered an HDR image to use as an environment map.

The problem is that when I then make a World material and load this image into the Environment Texture node it is totally out of alignment with where the sun object is in my sky.

My camera is in the World center, and I've tried various rotation settings, including clearing its rotation. No luck.
I've also tried to shift the alignment of the Environment Texture node's image via its Vector input, but that caused nothing to show up at all.
Any ideas what I need to do differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To transform an environment texture you'll want to manipulate the *Generated* coordinates:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know how to control this! Now knowing this I realize that, when rendering the Camera should be rotated X:90 Y:0 Z:0 (placed in the World center, of course) - and the rotation in the Mapping node when using that rendered image should be X:0 Y:0 Z:-90. Of course, we could choose to render with the Camera at a different rotation, but in any case the mapping rotation will differ from the Camera rotation, and these values seem to be the easiest to manage.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/environment-texture-for-background-does-not-show-up-in-node-editor