# How to scale an environment texture in the world section?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, transforms

Is there a way to resize the texture when using an image texture in the world section?
I have a texture that surrounds the scene (like a panorama).
It seems you can use it at a fixed size and rotation, with no way to tile or scale the texture.

It might maybe be possible to do this with nodes, but I could not find a way how to do this.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33161/599

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've edited your question to try and help clarify it. If you disagree with any of my edits, feel free to [edit] it again or roll back my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a panoramic background that surrounds the entire scene like you say, then scaling it doesn't really make sense. What you probably want to do instead is move the camera farther back and increase the *Focal Length* in *Camera Settings > Lens*:

[image]

For rotation, see [Rendered environment map is misaligned to World](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33161/rendered-environment-map-is-misaligned-to-world?lq=1)

Comment: that link for rotation answered my question thanks . in your answer you keep the camera pointed to one front direction only  , but in my situation i would turn the camera around and see also the back and the sides next to me.